# Where it goes the paper size information in a script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, pdf

I'm using this scrip to save to pdf but I need to make it Size A5 and Landscape Orientated
I have found some parameters but I don't know how to combine

```
function checkSheet() {
var sheetName = "OS";
var folderID = "FOLER ID"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
var docID = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange('B6').getValue();
var pdfName = "OS "+docID+".pdf";

//Copy whole spreadsheet
var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

//delete redundant sheets
var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
}
}

var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
//repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references) 
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

//save to pdf
var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
      

//Delete the temporary sheet
DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

source: [Exporting Google SpreadSheet to PDF (filename referring to a cell D7)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120712/exporting-google-spreadsheet-to-pdf-filename-referring-to-a-cell-d7)

That is the code for paper size:

```
var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/'
      + 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  //the file ID
      + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
      + '&size=LETTER'
      + '&portrait=true'
      + '&fitw=true'       
      + '&top_margin=0.50'              
      + '&bottom_margin=0.50'          
      + '&left_margin=0.50'             
      + '&right_margin=0.50'           
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'
      + '&pagenum=false'
      + '&gridlines=false'
      + '&fzr=FALSE'      
      + '&gid='
      + 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';       //the sheet's Id
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The code "for the paper size" shown at the end of the question doesn't have a place in the previous code at the beginning as it's is intended to be used with `UrlFetchApp` but the beginnings code is using `DriveApp`. Where do you found that code?

Comment: Related: [1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/142382/88163), [2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108399/88163)

Comment: Ruben, that was the source, indeed. is there a way to make paper size work on the other code or to modify the main code to integrate the paper size?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add proper attribution of the source and show what you tried or describe where do you get stuck to adapt the script to your needs.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Webapps. Your code is the same as referenced in Webapps (Sept 2018): [Exporting Google SpreadSheet to PDF (filename referring to a cell D7)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/120712/196152) and also "Docs Editor Help" (Nov 2020): [How to save G-Sheet or Doc as PDF within Drive](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/82026689/how-to-save-g-sheet-or-doc-as-pdf-within-drive?hl=en). This script was explicitly designed without regard for paper size. You need to modify your script and base it on one of the examples referenced by @Rubén. The key is the use of `UrlFetchApp.fetch`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch convert Google sheets in a specific directory to PDF and email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108399/batch-convert-google-sheets-in-a-specific-directory-to-pdf-and-email)

Comment: @Rubén just edit

Answer (score 1):

You want to add page size and orientation parameters to a script to save a sheet as PDF. To do this, your script must use the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` method ([Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?hl=en))

The following is an adaptation of your script with the relevant elements of the WebApps question/answer [Batch convert Google sheets in a specific directory to PDF and email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108399/196152).

---

```
function savesheetAsPDF() {
  var sheetName = "OS";
  var folderID = "177xwnrZRS8LUIpfqgcV0TGxcOTNvJSxn"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var docID = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange('B6').getValue();
  var pdfName = "OS "+docID+".pdf";

  //Copy whole spreadsheet
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  //delete redundant sheets
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }

  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", destSpreadsheet.getId());



  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=A5'                           // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=false'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

  
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  // Convert the sheet to PDF
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + destSheet.getSheetId(), {
  headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
  var theBlob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName)
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob)

  //Delete the temporary sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);

}
```